# E.O. Datepicker Duration between two datepicker

Tags: c#, asp.net

in my Reservation.aspx webpage i have a E.O. datepicker .How can i get the duration of two datepicker and show it on a textbox .. using c# codes, im using visual studio 2008.. thanks for any reply .. Need reply now..

Answer (score 0):

Just by writing:

```
TimeSpan duration = datePickerEnd.SelectedDate - datePickerBegin.SelectedDate;
```

you'd get duration. You can format this duration like you'd like, see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) article for reference.